# Heroku returning 404 but no error on logs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my reactjs (first) app on heroku, but i'm getting some trouble to get it online. I have no builds error, but when i try to launch my app i'm getting the "Cannot get /" error.

So on the Heroku logs i'm not getting any errors but only the heroku[routers] info with a 404 satus.
I did verify that my dist folder is not in .gitignore, try to add heroku logger (without success), add some code to package.json, server.json and webpack.config.js (without success).

my package.json (only important part) :

```
"engines": {
"node": "9.7.0",
"npm": "5.6.0"
 },
"dependencies": {
"@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3",
"axios": "^0.17.1",
"babel-core": "^6.26.0",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"css-loader": "^0.28.9",
"dotenv": "^5.0.0",
"express": "^4.16.2",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
"faker": "^4.1.0",
"heroku": "^7.24.4",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
"logger": "0.0.1",
"material-ui": "^0.20.2",
"react": "^16.2.0",
"react-dom": "^16.2.0",
"react-draggable": "^3.3.0",
"react-img-zoom": "^0.1.0",
"react-magnifier": "^3.0.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
"react-tap-event-plugin": "^3.0.2",
"reactjs-popup": "^1.4.1",
"style-loader": "^0.19.1",
"twilio": "^3.28.0",
"twilio-video": "^1.15.2",
"webpack": "^3.12.0",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^2.0.4",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.21.0"
},
"scripts": {
"build": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack",
"start": "node server",
"start:prod": "npm run build && node server.js"
},
```

my webpack.config.js :

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
require("dotenv").config();

var configFunc = function(){
var config = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: [
        __dirname + "/app/app.js"
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: "babel-loader",
                exclude: [/node_modules/]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss|css)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            hash: true,
            template: path.join(__dirname , "/app/index.html"),
            inject: "body"
        }),
        new webpack.BannerPlugin("React Twilio"),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("[name]-[hash].css")
    ]};
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "PROD") {
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin());
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: "commons",              
        filename: "commons.js"
    }));
}
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "DEV") {
    config.entry.push('webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true');
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
}
return config;
}();

module.exports = configFunc;
```

my server.js :

```
require("dotenv").config();
var path = require("path");
var express = require("express");
var webpack = require("webpack");
var faker = require("faker");
var AccessToken = require("twilio").jwt.AccessToken;
var VideoGrant = AccessToken.VideoGrant;

var app = express();
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "DEV") { // Configuration for development environment
var webpackDevMiddleware = require("webpack-dev-middleware");
var webpackHotMiddleware = require("webpack-hot-middleware");
var webpackConfig = require("./webpack.config.js");
const webpackCompiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(webpackCompiler, {
  hot: true
}));
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(webpackCompiler));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "app")));
} else if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "PROD") { // Configuration for production environment
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist")));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
});
}

app.use(function(req, res, next){
console.log("Request from: ", req.url);
next();
})

// Endpoint to generate access token
app.get("/token", function(request, response) {
var identity = faker.name.findName();

// Create an access token which we will sign and return to the client,
// containing the grant we just created
var token = new AccessToken(
    process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
    process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY,
    process.env.TWILIO_API_SECRET
);

// Assign the generated identity to the token
token.identity = identity;

const grant = new VideoGrant();
// Grant token access to the Video API features
token.addGrant(grant);

// Serialize the token to a JWT string and include it in a JSON 
response
response.send({
   identity: identity,
   token: token.toJwt()
});
});


var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Express server listening on *:" + port);
});
```

and my Procfile :

```
web: npm run start:prod
```

You can find my app at this link : https://salty-dawn-74805.herokuapp.com/

For information my app is inspired by this tutorial : https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/03/video-chat-react.html
You can clone this repository to reproduce : https://github.com/kimobrian/TwilioReact.git

The only error message i get is this (and obviously my website is working well on localhost):

```
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=salty-dawn-74805.herokuapp.com request_id= fwd= dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=20ms status=404 bytes=383 protocol=https
```

Hope someone can help me, i'm new to reactjs and it's the first time i'm deploying a reactjs app.

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found for others who maybe will have the same error ! 
It was really stupide : heroku node_env is "production" and i was verifying node_env equals "prod". :'(